# IMO 1994 problem 5

Tags: functions, proof-explanation, contest-math, functional-equations, monotone-functions

**Question:**

> Let $S$ be the set of real numbers strictly greater than $-1 .$ Find all functions $f: S \rightarrow S$ satisfying the two conditions:$$$$
>   1. $f(x+f(y)+x f(y))=y+f(x)+y f(x)$ for all $x$ and $y$ in $S$$$$$
>   2. $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is strictly increasing on each of the intervals $-1<x<0$ and $0<x$

**My doubt** -

I am having trouble with first few lines of the solution that was given in my book...

***Let f be a function of desired type.since $f(x)/x$ is strictly increasing on (-1,0), equation $f(x)=x$ can have at most one solution in (-1,0)....***

I didn't able to understand why this is true,is there a reason **without calculus** of this...if there is not then I will also manage to understand with calculus...

Thankyou

Comment: Let $g(x)=f(x)/x$.  Since $g$ is strictly increasing on $(-1,0)$, the equation $g(x)=1$ cannot have more than $1$ solutions.  If two solutions $x=a$ and $x=b$ were to exist with $a<b$, then $g(a)=1$ and $g(b)=1$.  This is a contradiction because $g$ is strictly increasing, so $g(a)<g(b)$ must be the case.

Comment: Ahh,I missed it .. thanks

Comment: Don't post pictures so that the future users could search by words. (:

Answer (score 1):

If $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is strictly increasing in $(-1,0)$, then it can only cut the line $y = 1$ at most once (as otherwise, it has to "come back down" and cut it again. Whenever it cuts the line $y = 1$, we have $\frac{f(x)}{x} = 1 \implies f(x) = x$. Conversely, whenever $f(x) = x$, we have $\frac{f(x)}{x} = 1$, so it only has at most one solution.